# $ character on PHPDoc @property declaration

Tags: php, phpdoc

In some places the name of a @property declaration using PHPDoc have $ sign such as:

```
/**
 * @property string $mystring
 */
```

But in other places the name appears without the $ sign such as:

```
 /**
  * @property string mystring
  */
```

PHPStorm makes no apparent difference between both, and the documentation [here](https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/property.html) just says '[name]', so I'm wondering what is the correct way if there is any.

Comment: The standard way is `@property string $mystring`

Comment: where is that written? I couldn't find anything myself

Comment: [Here](https://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.property.pkg.html), i.e.

Comment: it just says description, the fact that they use $ for the examples doesn't in my opinion exclude other forms

Comment: Obviously it doesn't exclude nothing, you are free to write your preferred way. But the example is clear: `@property mixed $regular`. This is the standard, most used way, not the mandatory way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example given [here](https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/property.html) has the `$` so I'd use the dollar.

Also, php **annotations** should start with `/**` (double *)

Comment: I know about the /** I just wanted to write one line of a bigger example :)

Comment: Another good point here is that phpstan only supports with `$` sign.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find anything on this matter concerning the [PSR-standards](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#4-2-properties). Although as stated by @LMS94, the example onn the PHP docs could be taken into account.

You could just add the `$` sign to avoid confusion...